# Firebase Array or Object - How to get child data or check if data exist

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Stuck for 2 days now in this problem.

I have only userEmail in my FireBase and I've tried everything in the firebase doc but I can't seem to get only the emails/values in my firebase.

What I am trying to do is to see if the email already exist in the database. This is not for User so I am not using UserAuth.

I am using Ionic, Angular

Here's my Factory/Service

```
app.factory('FirebaseUsers', ['$firebaseArray', '$firebaseObject', function($firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {
    var fireUsers     = new Firebase("https://blah.firebaseio.com");
    var usersArr      = $firebaseArray(fireUsers);
    var usersObj      = $firebaseObject(fireUsers);

    var FirebaseUsers = {
            all:    usersArr,
            al2:    usersObj
    };
    return FirebaseUsers;
}]);
```

My Firebase

**blahblah**:

```
-KJPNPaY-ijviTLCuYX6
 userEmail: "email@yahoo.com",
 userPhone: "000000000000000"

-KJPQBYqE0QoWr5G47IC
 userEmail: "email@gmail.com"
```

How do I get only the userEmail OR a simple way to check if a certain email already exist in firebase?

also, why does the output of firebase comes with different functions and prototype?

Comment: You first need to put a listener on your root reference to get all your data locally. Once you have your data locally iterate over all the children of your root reference until one of the child of the child of root reference has the value of userEmail matching with your user email.

Comment: Don't load your data like that. Please query for the data you are looking for. [Retrieving Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data#read_data_once) and in the Sorting and Filtering section -> equalTo(). Also better examples on Firebase old documentation site here [Retrieving Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html)